# Can we save scene of SceenKit as Autocad file format(.DXW or .DFX)

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, file-format

I am working on an AR measuring app in swift and after adding few nodes of SCNVector3 on my sceneView I want to save it to a .DXW or .DFX file so that I can check to see it in Autocad. I am wondering whether it is possible or not.

I was also checking Apple documentation for this delegate method. But not sure.

```
write(to:options:delegate:progressHandler:)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you can find example of exporting face  vector information to stl model, I’m pretty shure you can create .DXW or any other text based files same way:

https://github.com/heinrisch/faceid-to-stl